# gem install spree_auth_devise shows "dependancy conflicts"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree, spree-auth-devise

When i installed a spree_auth_devise it shows conflicting dependency chains.
How to resolve this ?

[image: Conflicting dependency]

for resolving i tried the following
[image]

After running these commands then also same errors are displaying when installing "gem install spree_auth_devise-1.3.1.gem".

Comment: When running this : gem install spree_auth_devise same error .

Comment: which spree version you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Go into your Gemfile.lock and (carefully!) remove the master references (not dependency references) to those conflicting Gems. You'll recognize the master references because they are alphabetical below soemthing that looks like this:

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
```

Remember, you're only looking for the top-level references, not ones inside other gem dependencies.

Delete the offending ones and re-run bundle install, that should fix your problem. (but be care to note whatever has changed in your Gemfile.lock and pay attention to which things got upgraded)

Comment: You're referencing spree_auth_devise 1.3.1 and spree-core version 2.4! That's your problem. Delete the spree_auth_devise references to 1.3.1 like I said above and bundle install should just automatically upgrade spree_auth_devise to the right version